# PHP associative 2 dimensional array of string recources

Tags: php, associative-array

Below is my code:

```
<?php 

$text_res = array(
     'eng' => array('chapter' => 'Chapter'),
     'rus' => array('chapter' => 'Глава')
     );

echo $text_res['eng']['chapter'];

?>
```

why is it printing empty string?

Comment: Works for me too: http://3v4l.org/DmvO9

Comment: Have you tried adding `mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');` at the top of your file and checking that it's saved with UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: Bratka,nu zachem ty tak pozorishsia?))

Comment: Actually I simplified the code above. I tried it and it works.

Comment: The code that does not work is following:

Comment: $text_res = array(
     'eng' => array('chapter' => 'Chapter'),
     'rus' => array('chapter' => 'Глава')
     );


function get_text_sub_header($lang)
{
    return $lang."=".$text_res[$lang]['chapter'];
}

echo get_text_sub_header('eng');

Comment: The php shell was very useful thanks, at least it shows me the errors. I use PHP very occasionally, please forgive my ignorance

Comment: the problem is in the $text_res scope. I expected this var would be visible within the function

Answer (score 0):

This particular code works. The question was asked not quite correctly. See the comments